# Metamask stuck at Unknown network ID when trying to interact with local Ganache network

Tags: solidity, ethereum-wallet-dapp, metamask, javascript, jquery

I'm getting unknown network ID error on transferring a token in meta mask as in the image below. I'm using local network with ganache. I can transfer from metamask account to another after transferring to metamask account from console. but i can't transfer to metamask account from deployed account

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

MetaMask can only send ether from their own accounts. If your want to send from a different address you have to import the private key first.

In the second screen shot it seems you are trying to buy ether, that service is only available in mainnet. For public testnet it will redirect you to a public faucet, and for private testnet it is not available.

If you are running ganache for your private testnet can import the private keys in MetaMask, they are show when ganache starts.